# Space Between Card Elements in a Hand in HTML Until They Begin to Overlap

Tags: html, css

I have a grid with three columns; the two on the outside hold decks that don't change dimensions and the center column, `#hand`, holds playing cards. The cards in hand overlap once there isn't enough space to fully display all the cards, with the last one always shown with full width. I'm trying to add space between the cards that shrinks and fully disappears once there are enough cards for them to begin overlapping. I extensively played around with gap, padding, and margin but can't reach this desired effect!

Desired effect when not overflowing:

[image]

Desired effect when overflowing/overlapping:

[image]

```css
#row-wrapper {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: auto minmax(0, auto) auto;
            justify-content: space-between;
            gap: 30px;
        }
    
        #hand {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
        }
    
        .card {
            flex: 1 0 0;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            width: 100px;
            height: 150px;
            background-color: yellow;
        }

        #hand > .card:nth-child(even) {
            background-color: red;
        }

        #hand > .card:nth-child(odd) {
            background-color: blue;
        }

        .card:last-child {
            flex: 0 0 auto;
        }
```

```html
    <div id="row-wrapper">

        <div><div class="card"></div></div>

        <div id="hand">

            <!-- remove some cards below to illustrate them not overlapping -->
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>

        </div>

        <div><div class="card"></div></div>

    </div>
```

Comment: My suggestion would be to add a 'gap' attribute to the cards in hand, and have media queries to lower the gap until a certain width, in which case it would be 0.
If you wanted to loop some javascript in to take the card count and determine gap that way it could work as well

Comment: @iamaword I'm looking for something responsive/dynamic though to look nice with card drawing animations, etc. I was thinking adding some sort of element with different flex properties between the cards?